# Averaging rows from one pandas df to to another as mean (using two keys)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

DF1 looks like:

[image: mock up of 4 column table, two id columns, two data columns representing averages]

DF2 looks like:

[image: mock up of 3 column table, two id columns, one data column representing raw values]

I need to find the mean of Question_3 from DF2, then add it as Question_3_Mean to the appropriate row matching ID_1 and ID_2.

[image: mock up of 5 column table, two id columns, three data columns representing averages (third column is the average of the scores from DF2]

I feel that this is something relatively trivial to do in Pandas, but I am not sure about the nomenclature to use in order to find out how.

What I did originally was create a new sheet in Excel and manually (with formulas) combined the two IDs, then used a pivot to get the averages, then did a vlookup to match the results. I then used that as my df for my seaborn chart.

I'd like to do all of this in Pandas though because this "matching" is a task I have to do often and I want to cut out that manual step.

Comment: Please post your data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can try `groupby()` then `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).mean().add_suffix('_Mean'),
          on=['ID_1','ID_2'])
```